# Meaning and usage of のみか (vs. のみならず etc.)

Tags: particles

I came across のみか in this sentence in 日本語パワードリル, N2文法:

> ネットショップの開設により、国内**のみか**海外からも注文が来た。

I've not come across のみか before, but it seems to just mean ['not only'](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%AE%E3%81%BF%E3%81%8B).

Is a specific meaning/nuance or usage for のみか? Is it the same as のみならず, だけでなく, ばかりか, ばかりでなく, はもちろん, etc.?

Comment: Think of のみか as a parallel and synonym for ばかりか.

Comment: There is probably a typo in your sentence. Isn't から missing after 海外?

Comment: @naruto Yup, thank you for catching that. I've added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

のみか is much less common than any of the phrases you listed as alternatives. I probably have never used it myself in my entire life, and BCCWJ has less than 20 examples of this のみか. I'm a bit surprised that an N2 level textbook tries to teach it. It feels literary due to its rarity, but I think there is no semantic difference between it and ばかりか, etc.

Comment: Thank you! I had not come across it before either, and it didn't appear on jisho.org, or the J->E Weblio either, so I suspected it must be rare.